# How to get the X position at a specified chart item index?

Tags: chart.js

I'm drawing a Bar chart with multiple datasets and need to draw a vertical line at a specified item index, i.e.

```
// chartData:
{
  labels: ['lbl0', 'lbl1', 'lbl2'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'dataset1',
    data: [12.84, 13.75, 14.86]
  },
  {
    label: 'dataset2,
    data: [25.14, 15.61, 10.81]
  }]
}
```

is there any way to get the X coordinate of first or all tooltips belonging to label **lbl1**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `getPixelForValue`

```js
const chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
const x = chart.scales.x.getPixelForValue('lbl1');
```

You can also choose to use the annotation plugin where you can just give the label and it will draw the line for you:

https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/